# Convert Gmail Date to your DateTime as displayed in Gmail Account

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail-api, datetime-format

I am getting inbox messages using Gmail API in my c# ASP.net application. All messages are from different time zones(states/countries), I wanna display there date in my own time zone as it displays in Gmail App. I searched a lot for conversion between timezones but can't solve it may be i am not getting it properly.

My code for but i tried so far is: (Its working for most of messages but for few of them its not displaying right DateTime)

For Example:

> Time displayed in Gmail App: 30/11/2017 2:11 AM
>
> My code Input/ value from Gmail API: Wed, 29 Nov 2017 10:11:35 -0800

Below are some values i am getting from my current gmail inbox messages:

[image]

```
 var re = service.Users.Messages.List("me");
 re.LabelIds = "INBOX";
 re.Q = "is:all";
 var res = re.Execute();
 if (res != null && res.Messages != null)
 {               
   foreach (var email in res.Messages)
   {    
     var emailInfoResponse = service.Users.Messages.Get("me", email.Id).Execute();
    if (emailInfoResponse != null)
    {
      foreach (var mParts in emailInfoResponse.Payload.Headers)
      {
        if (mParts.Name == "Date")
        {
          date = mParts.Value;
        }          
      }
    }
  }
}

My Time Zone is: (UTC+08:00) Perth
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual data you get from Gmail API (hopefully it has timezone info)?

Comment: @EdSF just edited. plz check

Comment: It's confusing, just provide the actual datetime data you get **from Gmail API**.

Comment: Hi.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then edit your question accordingly.  It will be much easier to help you that way.  For example, in the above code, you start with `emailInfoResponse`, but we do not have any way of knowing what that is.

Comment: @EdSF and Matt edited my question.

Comment: Yeah, that's still not an MCVE.  Please *read and follow* the guidelines in the link I provided.  Thanks.

Comment: Please put this in your question: __The exact datetime value I get from the API is 'xxxxxxxx.'__ There are some easier ways to parse a custom datetime format, but we can be more helpful if we know the exact value you're getting.

Comment: I'm looking at [the Gmail API docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource) now, and it would seem the `internalDate` field would be more reliable to work with than the `Date` header.  Did you try working with that?

Comment: edited will add pic of all values in few seconds. Sorry have no idea about internal date will check it as well

Comment: @Matt Johnson I tried getting internal date but getting null value for all messages: date = email.InternalDate.ToString();

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
{
  "id": string,
  "threadId": string,
   ....
  "internalDate": long,
  "payload": {
   ....
```

> `internalDate` `long`
>   The internal message creation timestamp (epoch ms), which determines ordering in the inbox. For normal SMTP-received email, this represents the time the message was originally accepted by Google, which is more reliable than the Date header. However, for API-migrated mail, it can be configured by client to be based on the Date header.

REF: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages

Based on the above Google documentation, here's one way:

```
//Some epoch time in ms
var gmail_date = 1512007768005; 

//Get DateTime of epoch ms
var to_date = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(gmail_date).DateTime;

//This is your timezone offset GMT +8
var offset = 8;

Console.WriteLine(to_date - new TimeSpan(offset *-1, 0, 0));
```

Gets you [11/30/2017 10:09:28 AM](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bXDJdC)

Comment: i am not getting how to get its value i am getting null value for internal date. Can you please help a bit in this. I am using: date = email.InternalDate.ToString();

Comment: @EdSF -Don't manipulate the offset manually.  Use `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` with an appropriate id.  In this case, the id is `"W. Australia Standard Time"`

Comment: @Preet - Don't call `ToString`.  The `InternalDate` field in the .NET client library is a `long?` so just call `.Value`.  It won't be null if you are looking at the response from the `Get` call of the individual message.

Comment: @MattJohnson - I'd agree with you 100% though I've been bitten in the past when systems I don't control don't have those enumerations (I couldn't tell you why)...

Comment: It's not just an enumeration.  Time zone offsets can change within a given time zone (due to DST and other reasons).

Comment: @Matt Got the value thanks was using inside list messages instead of get.

Comment: @EdSF it says: DateTimeOffset does not contain a definition for FromUnixTimeMilliseconds  can only find FromFileTime in it

Comment: @Preet - That method was added in .NET 4.6.  You can either upgrade your target, or you can implement that method yourself.

Comment: Thank you @Matt, You are (Awesome) very supportive I must say:)

Comment: I'm curious is internalDate in UTC timezone?